# Coldfusion: Element ROOT.DSN is undefined in APPLICATION

Tags: coldfusion

I am supporting a legacy Cold Fusion system and I cannot understand why every now and then I get the following error:

> Element ROOT.DSN is undefined in APPLICATION.

The error appears seemingly on random places and does not make sense to me. If I understand how cold fusion works - every request first processes `Application.cfm`, right?

There we have:

```java
if (not isDefined('Application.Root')) 
    include '/lib/config/CreateRoot.cfm';
```

CreateRoot does some initialization and setting ROOT.DSN is one of them.

This doesn't make any sense to me, because usually the caller also loaded some stuff from database, so how come one function can "see" this and it's gone when we get into another? It's not ROOT.DSN but sometimes other settings, that we initialize the same way.

A retry is usually successful so the only explanation I can some up with is that the server is running some garbage collector and cleaning up some memory when this happens.

My questions are:

1. Why does that happen and why/when are Application variables lost?
2. How to prevent it?

Comment: What does the statement that sets `ROOT.DSN` actually do? It's always best to show us the code, not vaguely describe it. You def wanna be setting `Application.Root,DSN`, not just `root.DSN`. See my comment below against Al's answer regarding some potential cognitive dissonance that can occur re the relationship between Application.cfm and the application-scope (they are completely unrelated concepts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the correct scope it's an important factor to prevent these issues. Please use "application.root.ds" to make sure you are indeed calling the correct scope. The application variable will only reset if you do the following:

1. restart the application
2. rename the application
3. restart the machine, which inherently restarts the application as well on the server.
4. manually reset the application scope

other than that once the application runs for the first time you should always be able to access it and it should not restart.

Comment: So once we initialize the application scope - it should persist, right? I.e. whatever we set in `application.cfm` - we should be able to access it from any function inside a CFM or CFC file, right?

Comment: Correct! Application scope persists as a global variable in throughout the coldfusion application and it cease to exists when the application or server is shutdown.

Comment: No. Not correct. "whatever we set in application.cfm...". No. There is no correlation between "Application.cfm" and "the application scope". "Application.cfm" is just a file that is executed at the beginning of every *request*, and has nothing to do with applications. One _could_ set something in the application scope in there, provided one makes sure to not re-run the code every request. Also Application.cfm has not been the appropriate way of managing this sort of thing for about 20yrs. One ought to be using the lifeycycle event handler methods in Application.cfc for this sorta thing.

Comment: @Adam thanks for clarifying that.  I'm taken OP is referring to application scoped variables being set on the application.cfm file. Although not ideal, it is unfortunately still being used

Comment: Thank you, Adam. In the context of my question - you are both correct and sadly this is the last problem this application has, but life isn't perfect and as long as it does the job - reengineering it isn't worth the effort.

Shortly after posting this question, I discovered the root of my problems and could reproduce the "random" crash (which turned out wasn't random at all but related to a specific user action) and fixed it.